# C# Translating a few smaller arrays to one big

Tags: c#, arrays, math

Title may not explain fully what I want to do, so I made an image.

[image]

You can see there are 4 1D arrays(red numbers, black colored numbers are indexes), each of this array goes from 0 to 63. I want to somehow translate them, that for example, index 16 will point to first index of second array.

What I was thinking of, is a function where I give List of arrays and index that I want to get as input, and its returns me the index of array and exact index in this array as output.

I would like to have some hints or suggestions on how to proceed here to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Are you looking for [jagged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) arrays, perhaps? That image does very little to visualize your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that image does nothing for me. Is it written in a right-to-left language?

Comment: I don't understand. If `array0` has indexes from `0` to `63`, why would index `16` point to `array1`? I would think that index `64` would point to `array1[0]`.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you want as a return value? This doesn't make sense to me: "its returns me the index of array and exact index in this array as output"

Comment: Orientation of arrays doesn't matter at all, I just visualize it like that because vertices of 3d mesh plane goes like this(im sorry for confusion). Basically those four 1d arrays are arrays of vertices, each of my plane has 64 vertices, so indexes of vertices goes [0...63]. I want give some function value for example **16** and it returns to me **array1 and index 0.** [link](http://i.imgur.com/bQNJiFn.png). Thanks Alex for editing my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your image shows an interleaved data of 16 elements, so you want to have (showing an example of only two matrices because of space :D)

```
Global index
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15   16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array0 indexes                                  - Array1 indexes
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F -  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Global index
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48   49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array0 indexes                                  - Array1 indexes
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F - 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
```

To get it you can do something like this:

```
public class CompositeIndex
{
    public int ArrayNumber { get; set; }
    public int ElementNumber { get; set; }
}

public static CompositeIndex GetIndex(int GlobalIndex, int ArrayCount, int ElementsToInterleave)
{
    CompositeIndex index = new CompositeIndex();
    int fullArrays = GlobalIndex / ElementsToInterleave; //In your example: 16 / 16 = 1;
    index.ArrayNumber = fullArrays % ArrayCount; //In your example: 1 mod 4 = 1;

    index.ElementNumber = GlobalIndex - (fullArrays * ElementsToInterleave); //In your example: 16 - (1 * 16) = 0;
    return index;
}
```

Then, if you have 4 matrices and want to get the "global" index 16 you do:

```
var index = GetIndex(16, 4, 16);
```

This function allows you to use an indeterminated number of arrays and interleaved elements.

BTW, another time ask better your question, a lot more people will help you if they don't have to solve a puzzles to understand what you want...

Comment: Thanks you very much,that is what I need. And Im so sorry for confusing you, I'll try to be more clear next time.